# after join the two tables I want to pivot the the table to get the result as per the img attached. but I'm getting an error

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNaPu.png)

```
select  t1.action, t1.AttributeName,t1.AttributeValue,t2.istotal_indicator 
from tbl_ss_orderitems_IC t1 

   join 
 Tbl_ECC_breakdowns t2

 on t1.[Action]= t2.ECC_Charge_Actiontype

   PIVOT(MAX(t1.AttributeValue) FOR t1.AttributeName 
   IN (                                       
   ChargeAmount                       
   ,Currency                      
   ,Quantity                       
   ,UnitOfMeasure                      
   ,UnitRate    


   )) AS PIVOT_1
```

> error//Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 219 The column 'Id' was
>   specified multiple times for 'PIVOT_1'. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 206 The multi-part identifier "t1.action" could not be bound. Msg
>   4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 206 The multi-part identifier
>   "t1.AttributeName" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 206 The multi-part identifier "t1.AttributeValue" could not be
>   bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 206 The multi-part identifier
>   "t2.istotal_indicator" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subquery before `PIVOT`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    select  t1.action, t1.AttributeName,t1.AttributeValue,t2.istotal_indicator 
    from tbl_ss_orderitems_IC t1 
    join Tbl_ECC_breakdowns t2 on t1.[Action]= t2.ECC_Charge_Actiontype
  ) q
PIVOT(MAX(AttributeValue) FOR AttributeName IN (ChargeAmount,Currency,Quantity,UnitOfMeasure,UnitRate)) p
```